# How to embed this javascrip into Mathematica with a single input

Tags: javascript, html, css, wolfram-mathematica

In my research, I need to generate Fricke Polynomials. Luckily the job has been done for me on a website. However, it is in javascript+html+css so I am not sure how it works as I only use Mathematica. I was wondering if anyone could explain how I could make all of this work on a single javascript code with a single input (and where to put the input). My plan is then to just take the code and embed it in Mathematica as I have seen this is possible. The input is a word say made up of a's and b's say aabbbaa and an output is a polynomial. I do not need to understand the code really.

Thank you

```js
function Polynomial(){
    this.data = "";
    this.setData = function(str){
        this.data = str;
    }
    this.toString = function(){
        var s = this.data;  
        if (this.data.startsWith("x0y0z0"))
            s = s.replace("x0y0z0", "1");
        s = s.replace(/x0y0z0/g, "")
            .replace(/\s\+\s-/g, "</sup> - ").replace(/\s\+/g, "</sup> +")
            .replace(/x/g, "x<sup>").replace(/y/g, "</sup>y<sup>")
            .replace(/z/g, "</sup>z<sup>")
            .replace(/\s1x/g, " x").replace(/\s1y/g, " y").replace(/\s1z/g, " z");
        s += "</sup>";
        s = s.replace(/x<sup>0<\/sup>/g, "").replace(/y<sup>0<\/sup>/g, "")
            .replace(/z<sup>0<\/sup>/g, "")
            .replace(/x<sup>1<\/sup>/g, "x").replace(/y<sup>1<\/sup>/g, "y")
            .replace(/z<sup>1<\/sup>/g, "z");
        if (s.startsWith("1x"))
            s = s.replace("1x", "x");
        if (s.startsWith("1y"))
            s = s.replace("1y", "y");
        if (s.startsWith("1z"))
            s = s.replace("1z", "z");
        return s;
    }
}

function compareMonomial(m1, m2){
    m1s = m1.split(/[x|y|z]/g);
    m2s = m2.split(/[x|y|z]/g);
    if (m1s[3]< m2s[3])     return -1;
    else if (m1s[3] > m2s[3]) return 1;
    else if (m1s[2]< m2s[2])        return -1;
    else if (m1s[2] > m2s[2]) return 1;
    else if (m1s[1]< m2s[1])        return -1;
    else if (m1s[1] > m2s[1]) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

function addMonomial(m1, m2){
    m1s = m1.split(/[x|y|z]/g);
    m2s = m2.split(/[x|y|z]/g);
    coef = parseInt(m1s[0]) + parseInt(m2s[0]);
    if (coef == 0)
        return "ZERO"
    else
        return coef + "x" + m1s[1] + "y" + m1s[2] + "z" + m1s[3];
}

function subMonomial(m1, m2){
    m1s = m1.split(/[x|y|z]/g);
    m2s = m2.split(/[x|y|z]/g);
    coef = parseInt(m1s[0]) - parseInt(m2s[0]);
    if (coef == 0)
        return "ZERO";
    else
        return coef + "x" + m1s[1] + "y" + m1s[2] + "z" + m1s[3];
}

function mulMonomial(m1, m2){
    m1s = m1.split(/[x|y|z]/g);
    m2s = m2.split(/[x|y|z]/g);
    coef = parseInt(m1s[0]) * parseInt(m2s[0]);
    coefx = parseInt(m1s[1]) + parseInt(m2s[1]);
    coefy = parseInt(m1s[2]) + parseInt(m2s[2]);
    coefz = parseInt(m1s[3]) + parseInt(m2s[3]);
    if (coef == 0)
        return "ZERO";
    else
        return coef + "x" + coefx + "y" + coefy + "z" + coefz;
}

function add(p1, p2){
    if (p1.data == "")
        return p2;
    if (p2.data == "")
        return p1;
    var r = new Polynomial();
    p1Mos = p1.data.split(" + ");
    p2Mos = p2.data.split(" + ");
    var data = "";
    var k = 0; var current = p1Mos[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < p2Mos.length; i++){
        if (k >= p1Mos.length)
            data += " + " + p2Mos[i];
        else {
            while (k < p1Mos.length && compareMonomial(current, p2Mos[i]) < 0){
                data += " + " + p1Mos[k]; k++; current = p1Mos[k]; 
            }
            if (current == undefined)
                data += " + " + p2Mos[i];
            else if (compareMonomial(current, p2Mos[i]) == 0){
                if (addMonomial(current, p2Mos[i]) != "ZERO")
                    data += " + " + addMonomial(current, p2Mos[i]); 
                k++; current = p1Mos[k];
            }   
            else{
                data += " + " + p2Mos[i];
            }
        }
    }
    while (k < p1Mos.length){
        data += " + " + p1Mos[k]; k++
    }
    r.setData(data.substring(3)); 
    return r;
}

function sub(p1, p2){
    if (p2.data == "")
        return p1;
    if (p1.data == ""){
        //need to update here
        return p2;
    }
    var r = new Polynomial();
    p1Mos = p1.data.split(" + ");
    p2Mos = p2.data.split(" + ");
    var data = "";
    var k = 0; var current = p1Mos[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < p2Mos.length; i++){
        p2coef = p2Mos[i].split(/[x|y|z]g/)[0];
        if (parseInt(p2coef) < 0)
            p2MoNeg = p2Mos[i].substring(1);
        else
            p2MoNeg = "-" + p2Mos[i];
        if (k >= p1Mos.length)
            data += " + " + p2MoNeg;
        else {
            while (k < p1Mos.length && compareMonomial(current, p2Mos[i])< 0){
                data += " + " + p1Mos[k]; k++; current = p1Mos[k]; 
            }
            if (current == undefined)
                data += " + " + p2MoNeg;
            else if (compareMonomial(current, p2Mos[i]) == 0){
                if (subMonomial(current, p2Mos[i]) != "ZERO")
                    data += " + " + subMonomial(current, p2Mos[i]); 
                k++; current = p1Mos[k];
            }   
            else{
                data += " + " + p2MoNeg;
            }
        }
    }
    while (k < p1Mos.length){
        data += " + " + p1Mos[k]; k++
    }
    r.setData(data.substring(3)); 
    return r;
}

// multiply polynomial p1 (with array of monomials p1Mos) with a monomial m2 
function mulPM(p1Mos, m2){
    r = new Polynomial();
    var data = ""; 
    for (var i = 0; i < p1Mos.length; i++){
        if (mulMonomial(p1Mos[i], m2) != "ZERO")
            data += " + " + mulMonomial(p1Mos[i], m2);
    }
    r.setData(data.substring(3)); return r;
}
// multiply polynomial p1 with polynomial p2    
function mul(p1, p2){
    p1s = p1.data.split(" + ");
    p2s = p2.data.split(" + ");
    r = new Polynomial();
    for (var i = 0; i < p2s.length; i++){
        r = add(r, mulPM(p1s, p2s[i]));
    }
    return r;
}

function Fricke(s){
    var w = new Word();
    w.setWordString(s);
    w.reduce(); s = w.toString();
    var r = new Polynomial();
    var l = s.length;
    // Trivial case or case where 2 consecutive letters among last 4 letter
    // are the same
    if (l == 0){
        r.setData("2x0y0z0");
        return r;
    }
    if (l == 1){
        if (s == "a" || s == "A")
            r.setData("1x1y0z0");
        else 
            r.setData("1x0y1z0");
        return r;
    }
    if (s.charAt(l-1) == s.charAt(l-2)){
        var c = s.charAt(l-1);
        var s1 = s.substring(0, l-2);
        r = sub(mul(Fricke(s1 + c), Fricke(c + "")), Fricke(s1)); 
        return r;
    }
    if (l == 2){
        if (s == "ab" || s == "ba" || s == "AB" || s == "BA"){
            r.setData("1x0y0z1");
            return r;
        }
        else if (s == "aB" || s == "Ba" || s == "Ab" || s == "bA"){
            r.setData("1x1y1z0 + -1x0y0z1");
            return r;
        }
    }
    if (s.charAt(l-2) == s.charAt(l-3)){
        s = s.charAt(l-1) + s.substring(0, l-1);
        r = Fricke(s);
        return r;
    }
    if (l == 3){
        s = s.charAt(l-1) + s.substring(0, l-1);
        r = Fricke(s);
        return r;
    }
    if (s.charAt(l-3) == s.charAt(l-4)){
        s = s.substring(l-2, l) + s.substring(0, l-2);
        r = Fricke(s);
        return r;
    }
    // Case 2: w = x1Yx2y
    var t = s.charCodeAt(l-1) - s.charCodeAt(l-3);
    if ( t == 32 || t == -32){
        var w1 = new Word();
        w1.setWordString(s.substring(l-2, l));
        var s2 = s.substring(0, l-2) + w1.bar().toString();
        r = sub(mul(Fricke(s.substring(0, l-2)), Fricke(s.substring(l-2, l))),
                    Fricke(s2)); 
        return r;
    }
    // Case 3: w = ...Xyxy
    t = s.charCodeAt(l-2) - s.charCodeAt(l-4);
    if ( t == 32 || t == -32){
        r = Fricke(s.charAt(l-1) + s.substring(0, l-1));
        return r;
    }
    // Last case 4: w = ...xyxy
    r = sub(mul(Fricke(s.substring(0, l-2)), Fricke(s.substring(l-4, l-2))), 
                    Fricke(s.substring(0, l-4)));
    return r;
}
            
            
    
    
            
            
    
// Helper methods: 
function cancel2Char(src, i){
    dest = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
        dest[j] = src[j];
    for (var j = i; j < src.length - 2; j++)
        dest[j] = src[j+2];
    return dest;
}
function trim2Ends(src){
    dest = [];
    for (var j = 1; j < src.length - 1; j++)
        dest[j - 1] = src[j];
    return dest;
}

// Function to find the minimum equivalent class of a reduced cyclic word rc.
function minReduceCyclic(rc){
    var min = rc.clone();
    var W = new Word();
    for (var i = 0; i < rc.word.length; i++){
        W = rc.permute(i);
        if (min.compareTo(W) > 0)
            min = W;
    }
    return min;
}

function canonical(W){
    W.reduce();
    W.toReduceCyclic();
    W = minReduceCyclic(W);
    return W;
}

// CLASS Word
function Word(){
    this.word = [];
    this.setWord = function(w){
        this.word = w;
    }
    this.setWordString = function(s){
    // a-z = 1-26 && A-Z = -1 - -26;
        for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
            var c = s.charCodeAt(i);
            if (c >= 65 && c <= 90 )
                this.word[i] = -(c - 64);
            else if (c >= 97 && c < 122)
                this.word[i] = c - 96;
            else {
                this.word = []; return;
            }
        }
    }
    this.length = function(){ return this.word.length; }
}

Word.prototype.isReduce = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.word.length - 1; i++)
        if (this.word[i] == -this.word[i+1])
            return false;
    return true;
}

Word.prototype.reduce = function(){
    var i = -2; 
    while(i != this.word.length - 1){
        if (this.word.length == 0)
            return;
        for(i = 0; i < this.word.length - 1; i++)
            if (this.word[i] == -this.word[i+1]){
                this.word = cancel2Char(this.word, i);  
                break;
            }
    }
    return;
}

Word.prototype.toReduceCyclic = function(){
    this.reduce();
    while(this.word[0] == -this.word[this.word.length - 1])
        this.word = trim2Ends(this.word);
    return; 
}
    
Word.prototype.toString = function(){
    var s = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < this.word.length; i++){
        if (this.word[i] < 0)
            s = s + String.fromCharCode(-this.word[i] + 64);
        else 
            s = s + String.fromCharCode(this.word[i] + 96);
    }
    return s;
}

Word.prototype.bar = function(){
    var r = new Word();
    var w = r.word;
    for (var j = 0; j < this.word.length; j++)
        w[j] = - this.word[this.word.length - 1 - j];
    return r;
}

Word.prototype.permute = function(i){
    var r = new Word();
    var w = r.word;
    for (var j = 0; j < this.word.length; j++)
        w[j] = this.word[(j + i) % this.word.length];
    return r;
}

Word.prototype.isEqual = function(W2){
    var w1 = this.word;
    var w2 = W2.word;
    if (w1.length != w2.length)
        return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < w1.length; i++)
        if (w1[i] != w2[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}

Word.prototype.compareTo = function(W2){
    var w1 = this.word;
    var w2 = W2.word;
    var l = Math.min(w1.length, w2.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++){
        if (w1[i] < w2[i])
            return -1;
        if (w1[i] > w2[i])
            return 1;
    }
    if (w1.length > w2.length)
        return 1;
    if (w1.length < w2.length)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

Word.prototype.clone = function(){
    var r = new Word();
    w = r.word;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.word.length; i++)
        w[i] = this.word[i];
    return r;
}

Word.prototype.primitiveExp = function(){
    w = this.word; l = w.length;
    for(var i = 1; i <= l/2; i++){
        if (l % i == 0){
            found = true;
            test:
            for (var j = 0; j < l/i; j++)
                for (var t = 0; t < i; t++)
                    if (w[t] != w[t + j * i]){
                        found = false;
                        break test;
                    }
        }
        if (found)
            return l/i;
    }
    return 1;
}

// Need to debug
function concat(W1, W2){
    r = new Word();
    var w1 = W1.word;
    var w2 = W2.word;
    var w = []
    for (var i = 0; i < w1.length; i++)
        w[i] = w1[i];
    for (var i = 0; i < w2.length; i++)
        w[i + w1.length] = w2[i];
    r.setWord(w);
    return r;
}

// These are supposed to be surface word methods
// sw is a word and the order is a map, which
// maps characters in a word (1-k or (-1)-(-k)) to its order in the alphabet
function order(sw){
    var w = sw.word;
    var o = new Map();
    for (var i = 0; i < w.length; i++)
        o.set(w[i], i);
    return o;
}

function findCharPos(sw, c){
    for (var i = 0; i < sw.word.length; i++)
        if (sw.word[i] == c)
            return i;
}
        
    
    
var time;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#compute").click(function(){
    $("#note").text("Note: Computing.....");
        time = new Date().getTime();
        setTimeout(function(){
            new Promise(compute).then(doneCompute("Note: Done! The computation time is about "));
        }, 50);
    });
    
    $("#reset").click(function(){
        $("#note").text("Note:");
        $("#word").val("");
        $("#fpOutput").text("");
    });
});

function compute(value){
    $("#fpOutput").html(Fricke($("#word").val()).toString());
    $("#fpOutput").slideDown("slow");
}

function doneCompute(value){
    $("#note").text(value + (new Date().getTime() - time - 50) + " milliseconds.");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="fricke.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Word.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Polynomial.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Computing Fricke Polynomial for word with 2 generators a and b</h2>
<br>
<b>Word: </b>
<input type="text" class="inputText" id="word"></input><br><br>
<br><br>
<button class="button" id="compute">Compute</button>
<button class="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
<br><br>
<div id="note">Note:</div>
<br><br>
<div class="slide">Fricke Polynomial</div>
<div class="output" id="fpOutput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm unclear what you want to happen with the output.

Comment: @AHaworth All I want, is somehow to get this into mathematica. I input the word, it outputs the polynomial. Nothing fancy. I think it is sufficient to make this into a single javascript code. Then Mathematica can handle it, as long as i understand how I can put in the input

Comment: You're going to have to learn enough javascript to either pull out and alter the pieces you need in order to embed it in Mathematica, or learn enough javascript to convert it into a Mathematica expression. If you run into problems which research and effort do not solve, then ask specific questions here.